# What's wrong with my ajax POST?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to populate new select menu (#school) from db table based on previous selection (#region) with ajax. I wanna get something like that: If there's no result, then hide #school and #class and show only error message. If search. php found results, then show at first school, if school selected too, then show #class.

What's wrong with my ajax POST? it doesn't get anything from db. Please help me to get it work.
my js looks like that

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#school").hide();
    $("#class").hide();
searchSchool = function(regionSelect){
var selectedRegion = $("select[name*='"+regionSelect.name+"'] option:selected").val();
if (selectedRegion!='0'){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : "core/code/includes/search.php",
    data: {region_id: selectedRegion},
    success: function(result, status, xResponse){
        if (result!=''){
            $("#school").show();
            $("#class").show();
            $("#school").html(result);
            $("#error").hide();
        }else{
            $("#error").html("There is no school found in this region");
            $("#school").html('');
            $("#school").hide();
        }
    },
    error: function(e){
        alert(e);
    }
    });
}else{
    $("#error").html('Please select a region first');
    $("#school").html('');        
    $("#school").hide();
    $("#class").hide();
}
}
});
```

and search.php

```
<?php
require 'db.php';
if(isSet($_POST['region_id'])) {
$region_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['region_id']);
$res=$db->query("SELECT * FROM schools  WHERE id='".$_POST['region_id']."'");
while ($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
echo '<option value="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[1].'</option>';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: debug your SQL query via phpMyAdmin (or similar) to see if it should return something, and after debug what `$res` content is (via `var_dump` or `print_r`)

Comment: What's wrong is that you have an SQL-injection hole!

Comment: First of all, read this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php - then look what's in "result" (console.log).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like:

```
$res=$db->query("SELECT * FROM schools  WHERE id='".$_POST['region_code']."'");
```

should be:

```
$region_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['region_id']);
$res=$db->query("SELECT * FROM schools  WHERE id='$region_id'");
```

also don't forget to use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), as mentioned.
Note that if you use the `mysqli` lib, you need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: Just to make sure,are you invoking your `searchSchool()` function ? And do you have `$_POST['region_id']` in your code, instead of `$_POST['region']` or something else?

Comment: yes i did. I changed script. Take a look at my updated question. now it works 'till gets result. If there's no result it works well. But if it got result one time, script doesn't work after it.

Comment: @Tural Teyyuboglu, does browser's error console have anything in it? If you use Firefox, it can be opened with ctrl+shift+j or tools->error console (at least on v3.6)

Answer (score 0):

`data: "&region_id="+selectedRegion,` looks wrong to me. I would use `data: {region_id: selectedRegion},`.

Also, see [@stewe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227477/whats-wrong-with-my-ajax-post/7227515#7227515) about using `region_code` instead of `region_id`.